# Can we apply 'case' to any type of 'cases'?

Tags: vocabulary

I know that we can apply **case** to a **suitcase**.

But does it happen with the other type of **cases**?

Can we apply **case** to a **briefcase**, **pencil case**, **attaché case**, **vanity case**, etc?

For instance, when asking for a **briefcase**:

> Can you pass me my **case**? (briefcase)

Comment: I don't understand why you would have doubts. Even a *really* figurative usage such as *He's a complete nutcase!* allows variations like *He's a [right] case!* In a nutshell (*not* "nutcase"), ***a case is a case is a case*** - whether it's a briefcase, suitcase, pencil case, grammatical case, or whatever.

Comment: I understand your point, but why in the dictionary case = suitcase and no other cases have that special privilege?Macmillan: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/case_1#case_1__10 Oxford: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/case

Comment: For a non native speaker this is a bit confusing. I would be free to use *case* to whatever types of cases - briefcase, suitcase, etc. if case in the dictionary didn't have that particular meaning - 'suitcase'. Having that meaning it seems that - OK, I can say **case or suitcase** interchangeably, but not **case and briefcase**. (hope not to be too confusing :))

Comment: @FumbleFingers I (and several others, it would appear) think your comment looks like the answer :)

Comment: @WendiKidd: I'm sure someone can do better than that. From subsequent comments, it seems the problem is OP doesn't know how to evaluate a dictionary entry, rather than there being anything unusual about the way the word ***case*** can be used in English. ***I*** don't see anything problematic about the two dictionary entries OP has linked to (in a comment, though they should be in the question text itself). So it might be better for a non-native speaker to answer, since they may have a better understanding of *why* OP doesn't "get it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English (and I assume, all other natural languages) context is crucial. If no context has been established and you ask someone "Have you seen my case", they'll assume a luggage-sized one as the default. If you've already been talking about a pencil-case and refer to "the case", "pencil-" is established as the context. And in "he's a right case", the context ("he") cannot possibly apply to a suitcase (that's an "it"), hence we deduce the colloquial "head-case" or "nut-case".

Comment: Thank you!!! Finally someone humble enough to give a proper answer.